# handlebarjs counter to increment everytime when function is invoked

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

i have a handlebar js function, which will increase the positional values,

```
$(function() {
    var data = {
        names: [
            { name: "Andrew" },
            { name: "Brian" },
            { name: "Charlie" }
        ]
    };

    var positionCounter = 1;
    Handlebars.registerHelper('position', function() {
        return positionCounter++;
    });

    var $output = $('#output');
    var source = $('#template').html();
```

Result will be : `1 Andrew 2 Brian 3 Charlie`

again next time when i run, it will be same (`1 Andrew 2 Brian 3 Charlie`). But what i need is every time I invoke the function it should increment . for example :

```
First execution  : 1 Andrew 2 Brian 3 Charlie
Second execution : 4 Andrew 5 Brian 6 Charlie
Third execution  : 7 Andrew 8 Brian 9 Charlie
```

how can it be possible

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your helper works. Just run the below snippet to check.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = {
        names: [
            { name: "Andrew" },
            { name: "Brian" },
            { name: "Charlie" }
        ]
    };
  var positionCounter = 1;
    Handlebars.registerHelper('position', function() {
        return positionCounter++;
    });
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ul>
{{#each names}}
  <li>{{position}} - {{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

<ul>
{{#each names}}
  <li>{{position}} - {{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

<ul>
{{#each names}}
  <li>{{position}} - {{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```